# Instantiating a constructor based on runtime type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

At my workplace, I am working on a product that understands the types at runtime. A task has come up which requires me to read these types and store them into a C++ class based on what constructor is invoked. So far, I have given a thought on `std::tuple`, variadic templates and `std::vector` of `boost::any` and I could come up with something like

```
class Storage
{
   private:
       std::tuple<int,float,std::string> ti;
   public:
       Storage(....);
       Storage(....);
       ....          // constructors for all the combinations
};
```

We have our internal API that can tell me as to how many types are supplied at runtime, however, the problem is that I do not know in what fashion the elements will be supplied i.e it can be only 1 type or more than one or all three and so on.

As such I end up with a big switch-case block where I check possibilities for all of the inputs (i.e 1 type, 2 types and 3 types).

Is there any way I can solve this ? By some template meta-programming magic such that in the end I can get away from this big switch-case and just supply a single constructor and let compiler instantiate the constructor based on an input.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22560100/how-to-initialize-all-tuple-elements-by-the-same-arguments) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416653/tuples-of-unknown-size-parameter-types?rq=1) question but I couldn't see how it would fit for my use case.

Comment: Your problem is the order of argument to construct `ti` ?

Comment: Your question is unclear; could you describe what kind of input you can get and the matching output you expect: pseudo-code is fine, but do describe your *intent*. Also, there seems to be a mixing of concern: the type and number of elements being decided at runtime are orthogonal issues. Solving the type issue is the hard part, whereas a runtime count is par for the course for a `vector`.

Comment: Search the web for "software design factory" or "software dispatch".

Comment: @Recker if my answer is the accepted answer for the question then you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer, so that it becomes green. If you found a different solution then you should describe it here and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing this by heart. If it doesn't work I don't know who wrote it. I just hope I understand the problem correctly.

Make a helper structure that has all three members, as well as three flags that are set if corresponding members are set, and also overloaded member function that sets the members:

```
struct Helper
{
    int i;
    bool bi;
    float f;
    bool bf;
    std::string s;
    bool bs;

    void set(int i) { this->i = i; bi = true; }
    void set(float f) { this->f = f; bf = true; }
    void set(std::string s) { this->s = s; bs = true; }
};
```

Make a function template (actually three such templates) that take up to 3 parameters and return a `Helper` object:

```
template<class P1, class P2, class P3> Helper make(P1 p1, P2 p2, P3 p3)
{
    Helper h;
    h.set(p1);
    h.set(p2);
    h.set(p3);
    return h;
}

template<class P1, class P2> Helper make(P1 p1, P2 p2)
{
    Helper h;
    h.set(p1);
    h.set(p2);
    return h;
}

template<class P1> Helper make(P1 p1)
{
    Helper h;
    h.set(p1);
    return h;
}
```

Your `Storage` class should have one constructor with one parameter of type `Helper`, and use only the parameters that have a flag set. To use the system:

```
Storage storage = make(<any combination of up to 3 params>);
```